# what does 'div' in my css code mean?

Tags: css, html

For a long time I was having trouble displaying a button to the right of my input box. On some computers it worked but on other computers and in different resolutions it would be hidden under the input box, so the user couldn't even see it.

My code was something like (using simple_form in Rails):

```
<%= simple_form_for @review, :url => search_index_path, :method => :post, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
```

etc...etc...

With the help of Stackoverflow my css changed many times - spent days at it - and finally ended up like, which works perfectly:

```
.form-inline div { 
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

I'm just curious what that 'div' means? For example,

```
.form-inline { 
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

doesn't work. I thought 'div' is what you put in the markup code, like `<div form-inline>whatever</div>`, not in the css. Just curious...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Comment: I suggest you educate yourself on the CSS selectors. This one is called the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

Comment: sorry, I didn't know Stackoverflow was for such an elitist crew.

Comment: Christophe, sure seems like Marty was trying to be helpful. I can see how it might be read a different way, but I suggest taking his comment and suggestion at face value.

Comment: Well, sorry for that then. Just seems odd the way I got -3 votes for asking a genuine question. Edit: in fact, it's gone back up to 0. And I know what 'div' means now. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopheHarris Hmm. I didn't intend to make my comment sound aggressive, and I'm far from an elitist - just trying to give you a stern push in the right direction. Apologies.

Comment: @Marty Wallace cheers, no problem. Just frustrated when I saw so many down votes after about 10 seconds, so rash on my part. I actually read over your link, which was interesting.

Comment: I was trying to learn Haskell once and was silly enough to ask a basic question on here about it. I got to like -8 in about 60 seconds. Just happens with some questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This** `div` mean all div's elements in your elements with `.form-inline` class. They don't need to be children of `.form-inline` element. They just need to be in it.

Take this as an example:

```
<form class="form-inline">
   <div>a</div>
   <div>b</div>
   <p>Some text <div>d</div></p>
</form>
<div>c</div>
```

`div`s "a", "b" and "d" will be formated. `div` "c" will be not.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your answers, which I read over with interest. Unfortunately I can accept only 1 answer, so it will be this first one, and I'll accept +1 the others. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`.form-inline div` selector means apply this rule to every `div` that is a descendent of any element with class `form-inline`.

So for example:

```
<my-elem class="form-inline">
   <another-type />
   <div>I'll get this CSS rule</div>
   <something-else>
     <div>I'll get this CSS rule too</div>
   </something-else>
</my-elem>
```

HTML element names in CSS are not prefixed like for example classes (with .dot) or IDs (with #hash).

Answer (score 1):

It assigns that set of rules to *any div inside* the `.form-inline` element and not the `.form-inline` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The div in your code is a part of selector in CSS.

In plain English it would mean select any element/tag that has a class of .form-inline and than select all div's which are the decendants of that element and apply the following rules.

```
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 5px;
```

In your case you are using a Descendant Selector

[Descendant Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector)

The space between the two simple selector is called a combinatory.

[Selector Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref)

Comment: don't worry about them mate. they just think having high rep gives them that right. just read through the links to better understand CSS. +1 just to negate the downvotes

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of css selectors that you can use. You can find all of them here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html